# Combining similar structs in Swift

Tags: swift, struct

I have the following two structs:

```
struct Struct1 {
   let name: String
   let values: [Double]

   func calculateValues() -> [Double] {
   // Struct1 implementation
   }
}

struct Struct2 {
   let name: String
   let symbol: String
   let values: [Double]

   func calculateValues() -> [Double] {
   // Struct2 implementation
   }
}
```

The implementation of `calculateValues()` is different for `Struct1` and `Struct2`.

Coming from `ObjectiveC` I see there is a lot of similarites between the two, and it screams inheritance to me.  But as far as I know that doesn't work with structs in Swift.

I also tried `typealias Struct2 = Struct1`, but then I don't think I can add the extra property.

I can just leave it as is, but there may be a Swift way to somehow "combine" the two?

Comment: Inheritance seems like a very bad solution just to share implementation, or even property declarations.

Comment: Why not make them classes?  Polymorphism is a primary OOP feature.

Comment: @Sulthan: that's what I was thinking as well, so is there an alternative (besides using a class or composition as already answered). Will a `protocol` help in this case?

Comment: If you need the structs to have the same interface, you can use a protocol of course but both structs will look exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe using a `class` is better in this case.

Comment: I would restrain from using classes if they don't share any implementations. You should consider favoring composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using composition?

```
struct Struct2 {
   let struct1: Struct1
   let symbol: String

   func calculateValues() -> [Double] {
   // Struct2 implementation
   }
}
```

Comment: After thinking and tinkering a lot in a `PlayGround`, I think the way forward in my case is to use this Composite approach, in combination with a `Calculate` `protocol`.

Answer (score 1):

I would advocate possibly migrating to classes as an alternative, depending on the actual implementation of your structures (how many common properties and methods, etc). It seems from the example above that the two constructs *do* share properties; all but the additional property `symbol` and method `calculateValue`, which could be added by subclassing the first construct (if migrated to class usage). However if instances of the the two structures are never actually used interchangebly, e.g. in external functions (taking any of the two generically), possibly it's best to keep the two of then separate.

Anyway, since the question specifically covers structs: I think composition is the way to go here. I'll add an loosely related and alternative method below, however, to complement existing answer regarding construct composition.

---

If you were to have various very similar structures that differed only by a single function,  you could use a single structure to represent the different instance cases that the various original structures were intended to cover; replacing the function with a closure. You can let the closure have a default value (say, representing `calculateValues` in `Struct1` for you above), but have the alternative of being defined differently than default at initialization. Finally, you access the closure via a computed property in the construct.

Common structure:

```
struct MyStruct  {
    let name: String
    let symbol: String?
    let values: [Double]
    private let internalCalculateValues : ([Double], String?) -> [Double]

    var calculateValues: [Double] {
        return internalCalculateValues(values, symbol)
    }

    /* put default implementation of internalCalculateValues in init signature */
    init(name: String, values: [Double], symbol: String? = nil,
        calculateValues: ([Double], String?) -> [Double] = {
            // default implementation: dont make use of symbol
            return $0.0.map{ 2*$0 } }
        ) {
        self.name = name
        self.values = values
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.internalCalculateValues = calculateValues
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
/* use default calculateValues */
let s1 = MyStruct(name: "foo", values: [1.5, 3.0, 4.5])
print(s1.calculateValues) // [3.0, 6.0, 9.0]

/* use custom calculateValues  */
let s2 = MyStruct(name: "foo", values: [1.5, 3.0, 4.5]) {
    return $0.0.filter{ $0 > 2.5 }
}
print(s2.calculateValues) // [3.0, 4.5]

/* use custom calculateValues and make use also of 'symbol' 
   parameter in the closure                                  */
let s3 = MyStruct(name: "foo", values: [1.5, 3.0, 4.5], symbol: "^2") {
    print("Operated on values in array by: .\($0.1 ?? "")")
    return $0.0.map{ pow($0,2) }
}
print(s3.calculateValues)
    /* Operated on values in array by: .^2
       [2.25, 9.0, 20.25]                      */
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be better to just use protocol

```
protocol Struct12{
   let name: String{get set}
   let values: [Double]{get set}

   func calculateValues() -> [Double]
}
```